# How would I display H3 hexagons on top of Mapbox GL React native

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, react, h3

I want to make an interactive app where users can view crime rates in their area by pulling in geo-data from the met police website.

I have gotten the Mapbox map to display but I am trying to figure out how exactly would I render the hexagons on to the map. Like where would I put it.

Below is my code.  Where can I improve it?

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import MapboxGL from "@rnmapbox/maps";

MapboxGL.setAccessToken("<ACCESS-TOKEN-HERE>");

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  container: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

What code of block would accept the h3 hexagon logic?

Comment: did you find any solution for this yet?